# How to use custom properties from MUI theme object with custom props in emotion styled components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, emotion

I have added a custom object named `fTokens` to the MUI theme via Module augmentation in TypeScript

This is how my `theme.d.ts` looks like

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface FPalette { ...
  }

  interface FTokens { ...
  }

  interface FSpacing { ...
  }

  interface Theme {
    fPalette: FPalette;
    fTokens: FTokens;
    fSpacing: FSpacing;
  }

  interface ThemeOptions {
    fPalette: Partial<FPalette>;
    fTokens: Partial<Tokens>;
    fSpacing: Partial<FSpacing>;
  }
}
```

And I am trying to pass a custom prop `rowId` to `TableRow` of MUI

```
import MUITableRow, { TableRowProps as MUITableRowProps } from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

interface TableRowProps {
  rowId: number;
}

const TableRow = styled(MUITableRow)<TableRowProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.fTokens.surfaceHigh,
}));

export default TableRow;
```

I am getting TypeScript error as `Property 'fTokens' does not exist on type 'Theme'.ts(2339)`

UPDATE - I tried Type assertion using `as` keyword that is working for me but I don't know if this is the most elegant way to solve this?

```
const TableRow = styled(MUITableRow)<TableRowProps>(({ theme, rowId }) => ({
  backgroundColor:
    rowId % 2 === 0
      ? (theme as Theme).fTokens.surfaceHigh
      : (theme as Theme).fTokens.surfaceHighest,
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try import styled from '@mui/material/styles', not '@mui/system'

`import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';`

doc: https://mui.com/system/styled/#import-path

Comment: So there are multiple places from where one can potentially import `styled`, First it can be imported from `emotion`, Then second place `@mui/system` and third one which actually works is `@mui/material/styles`. Is this not a foot gun that the docs should talk about?

Answer (score 1):

The `theme` has the type `Theme`, which is the same type that your should probably have declared in the `ThemeProvider`. You can read the type declaration in the official repo here https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/styles/createTheme.d.ts#L28-L36

As you can tell, there are no `fTokens` according to the type declaration file, therefore throwing the error.

What you want to do to fix it is to start from the `ThemeProvider` to provide the color to the appropriate property, for example -- `palette`, THEN you can theme/styled the `TableRow` with the color you just added to your `ThemeProvider`.

Here's example code --

```
const TableRow = styled(MUITableRow)(({ theme }) => {
  return {
    backgroundColor: theme.fTokens.surfaceHigh
  };
});

export default function App() {
  const outerTheme = createTheme({
    fTokens: { surfaceHigh: orange[500] }
    // palette: { primary: { main: orange[500] } }
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={outerTheme}>
        <TableRow />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Documentation about `styled` utility here: https://mui.com/system/styled/

Random test in Codesandbox that doesn't throw error (except `<tr>` should not be child of `<div>`) https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-kowalevski-ppm6zh?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: As I mentioned in first line, I have added a `theme.d.ts` file where I have augmented the Theme and ThemeOptions type of MUI to add a object called `fTokens`

Comment: @KshitijV97 ah that's a good technique. I have updated the answer along with the CodeSandbox link.

Comment: Interesting, Check above answer as well, Just importing `styled` from `@mui/material/styles` fixed the issue, I could also fix it by explicitly asserting the type using `as`